# Most efficient way to find duplicates within non-grouped sections of a large hash

Tags: powershell, loops, hash, duplicates

I am trying to find the most efficient way of sifting out any duplicates in a large hash table which consists of almost 5k objects.

I am running all of this in Powershell. So, I have this large hash table which consists of (in essence) User's and Subscription Names

```
1. User_id  |  Sub_name
2. User_id  |  Sub_name

etc...
```

In most cases, there are 5+ lines for each `User_id` as each new line represents a subscription name that user is subscribed to.

What I need to do is this: Identify any duplicate subscriptions for each user. For example

```
1. mm1234 | sub_1
2. mm1234 | sub_4
3. mm1234 | sub_1
4. mm9999 | sub_1
5. mm9999 | sub_2
6. mm8888 | sub_1
7. mm8888 | sub_1
```

So, in the above example, I would need to remove lines `3` & `7`. Now, currently there is no actual grouping in terms of how users are grouped in the hash, they are just shoveled in. I'm wondering if it is possible to do it from the final product hash like seen above. Thoughts?

Comment: How does this data exist in PowerShell? Is it a actually a hashtable since I do not see unique keys? Is this in a text file? What's with the numbers?

Comment: Yep, it's a hash of hashes. An example of the hashes *INSIDE* of the main hash would look something like `@{user_uuid = 1234; lob = subscription name}` So, then you have 1 line for each subscription that a User is subscribed to, but they may be subscribed to the same one more than once, it is those instances I want to eliminate. The problem is that we can't just sort through each user since they all just exists as is but can be SORTED by user id which is helpful I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

If your large hash looks similar to this:

```
$hash = @{
    '1' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm1234'; 'lob' = 'subscription_1' }
    '2' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm5678'; 'lob' = 'subscription_1' }
    '3' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm1234'; 'lob' = 'subscription_2' }
    '4' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm5678'; 'lob' = 'subscription_5' }
    '5' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm1234'; 'lob' = 'subscription_3' }
    '6' = @{ 'user_uuid' = 'mm1478'; 'lob' = 'subscription_1' }
}
```

You could create a new result hash where the keys are the `user_uuid`'s and the values are arrays of uniquely sorted subscriptions (or `lob` as you call them)

```
$result = @{}
$hash.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $uid   = $hash.$_.user_uuid
    $value = $hash.$_.lob
    if ($result.ContainsKey($uid)) {
        # add to the subscriptions array for this user_uuid
        $result[$uid] = ($result[$uid] + $value) | Sort-Object -Unique 
    }
    else {
        # create an element for this user_uuid and make sure the value is an array
        $result[$uid] = @($value)
    }
}
```

The resulting Hashtable will have this content:

> ```
> Name          Value                                                                                                                                                                  
> ----          -----                                                                                                                                                                  
> mm1234        {subscription_1, subscription_2, subscription_3}                                                       
> mm1478        {subscription_1}                                                                                                                                                       
> mm5678        {subscription_1, subscription_5}
> ```

If you need to convert this back into the format of the original `$hash` (a hash of hashes), you can do something like this:

```
# recreate the large hash using the deduped values
$newHash = @{}
$count = 1
$result.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($value in $result.$_) {
        $newHash[$count++] = @{ 'user_uuid' = $_; 'lob' = $value }
    }
}
```